# Edit text is not showing type characters

Tags: android, android-edittext

On one fragment I have layout like

question.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/question"
    android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/question"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/question"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have an interface like this

[image]

But the problem is when I focus on `EditText` and try to write something in it, then nothing is happening. No text , no keyboard is showing.  If I click and hold on the `EditText` then it shows message that nothing to paste. Why the text is not entering in Edit Text?

Here is my code

```
public class ListFrag extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);       
        setListAdapter(new ListFragAdapter(
            new MyListData("Software Engineer", "Basit", "4 years"),
            new MyListData("Lt. Commander", "Kashif", "12 years"),
            new MyListData("Beautiful", "Hafsa", "23 years"),
            new MyListData("Electrical Engineer", "Wajahat", "7 years"),
            new MyListData("Doctor", "Mehreen", "12 years")));  
    } //end of onActivityCreated()

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {        
        MyListData listData = (MyListData)getListAdapter().getItem(position);       
        DetailFrag frag = (DetailFrag) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_capt);
        if (frag != null && frag.isInLayout()) {            
            getData(position, listData, frag);  
        }

    } //end of onListItemClick()

    private void getData(int position, MyListData listData, DetailFrag frag) {      
        String artist = listData.artist;
        String title = listData.title;      
        frag.setText(artist, title);        
    } //end of getData()

} //end of class ListFrag
```

Here is my Detail Fragment

```
public class DetailFrag extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question , container, false);
        return view;

    } //end of onCreateView()

    public void setText(String artist, String title) {

        TextView leftSide_artist = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.question);
        leftSide_artist.setText(artist);
        
    } //end of setText()

} //end of class DetailFrag
```

Thanks

Comment: you did't test it on device ??

Comment: no i just made it and tried to run it on emulator... is there any difference while running on emulator and on real device ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yup there is a difference , usually it happens in Landscap mode keyboard not pops up in AVD but will work fine on device, how i managed this

- Go to your emulator Setting >> Languages & Keyboard, turn off all dictionaries and Auto suggestions
- Go to AVD Manger and Edit you AVD, in 'Hardware' section click 'New' and add "keyboard support"
- Restart AVD

Try if it works for you

Comment: How can i go to emulator settings in eclipse? Thanks

Comment: nope, you have to use emulator, in you running emulator's menu there is an icon of Settings

Answer (score 1):

Another Possibility is that you set the hardwareAccelerated = false in your activity or your application in the AndroidManifest.xml